# How to remove a line in a document opened in vim if certain word occurs in it?

Tags: vim, vi

I am having a text document opened in vim and it is like this:

```
 ...100    .Z....              0.   ....01            .506
 ...100    ....04              1.   ....05            .182
 ...100    ....55            .312
 ...101    .Z....          -3280.   ....01            .638
 ...101    ....04              1.   ....05             .05
 ...101    ....55            .312
 ...102    .Z....           3310.   ....01             -1.
 ...103    .Z....          -1890.   ....05             .92
 ...103    ....30              1.   ....49            -9.5
 ...103    ....52           -.042   ....53           -.063
 ...103    ....55             .08
 ...104    ....34            .825   ....35            .175
 ...104    ....40              1.   ....51             16.
 ...105    ....35            .175   ....40              1.
 ...105    ....46            .825   ....51             21.
 ...106    .Z....          -1890.   ....06              1.
 ...106    ....30              1.   ....49             3.6
 ...106    ....52           -.042   ....53           -.063
 ...107    .Z....           -903.   ....06              1.
 ...107    ....38              1.
 ...108    ....06              1.   ....50             -.8
 ...109    .Z....            432.   ....31           -1.23
```

I want to remove the lines which have  `.Z....` . Is there a quick way to do it in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should have googled better

```
 :g/.Z..../d
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this in the command mode:

```
:%s/^.*\.Z\.\.\..*$//g
```

note: `\.` escaping `.` metacharacter; `.*` - any character; `^` from beginning `$` to the end of line